# If $\{u,v\}$ is an orthonormal set in an inner product space, then find $\lVert 6u-8v\rVert$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

If $\{u,v\}$ is an orthonormal set in an inner product space, then find $\|6u-8v\|$.

That's pretty much it. I'm trying to study for a quiz and can't figure it out. There are no examples in my book to help me out, just a question. I know that if $\{u,v\}$ are orthonormal then $\|u\|=1$ and $\|v\|=1$, but how does that translate into $\|6u-8v\|$? Thanks in advance to anyone that can help!

Comment: **Hint:** $\|u\|^2=\langle u,u\rangle$ and $\langle u,v\rangle=\|u\|\|v\|\cos(\theta)$, where $\theta$ is the angle between $u,v$.

Comment: And orthonormal also means that $\langle u,v \rangle = 0$

Comment: It isn't -2...is it?

Comment: A norm can not be negative.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm so lost. I'm trying to understand what I can do with those properties, but I simply don't understand. My professor is trying to cram in 3 chapters before our final and I'm still trying to understand the ultimate goal here. (in reference to the problem and sets being orthonormal)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compute the square of the norm and use the definition of the inner product as being bilinear:

$\|6u-8v\|^2 = \langle 6u-8v, 6u-8v \rangle = 36\langle u,u \rangle - 48\langle u, v \rangle - 48 \langle v,u \rangle + 64 \langle v,v \rangle$.

Now use that  $u$ and $v$ are orthonormal and the fact that $\langle w,w \rangle$ is the squared length of the vector $w$. Take the square root to obtain the answer.

Comment: That's brilliant. Thank you very much. Now I see what the hint was for. As a side question, do you have a good reference for learning more about orthonormality? My book is utterly useless in terms of examples. If I can't see it used in an example, I don't understand the application. Thanks in advance! If not, don't sweat it--you've helped enough.

Comment: This is one of those questions that is just checking your understanding of definitions and basic manipulations, i.e. what the norm is and bilinearity of the inner product. I wouldn't say there is much of an application here. My favorite linear algebra book is probably Linear Algebra Done Right by Sheldon Axler, which has great chapters on inner product spaces. As an application, he discusses how these concepts can be used to find very accurate approximations to certain functions by polynomials.